# How much does it cost to get some help from an immigration lawyer?

Tags: united-kingdom

Do you have any idea how much does it cost to get some help from an immigration lawyer? I believe my case is kind of simple as we can prove all what immigration ask in order to obtain a residence card for a EEA family member. However, some sections of the application are confusing to me. I believe immigration lawyers have lots of exerience in this matter and know better how to fill out the applications.

Comment: What part of the application are you confused with?

Comment: This depends on where you are, what country, what you need, how many hours...it's too broad in its present form.  I'm closing as too broad, but if you edit with more details, it might be answerable.